# How to show a request only one time if it repeat in every 200 milliseconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some data in PHP which has been encoded in JSON format. I have used that data by using `getJSON` of jQuery. My code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(done,200);
});

function done() {
    setTimeout(updates, 200); // Call updates in 200ms
}

function updates(){
    $.getJSON("phpdata.php", function(data) {
        //some action..
    });
}
```

`phpdata.php` is the file which holds JSON encoded data. Now as you can see I have some functions which update my `$.getJSON` every 200 milliseconds. I did that to get changes to the data on the site from my database without a page refresh/reload. I know it does my work fine, but I have only one thing which I want to change if possible.

As I make a request using `getJSON` every 200 milliseconds, when I check on the 'Network' tab of 'Developer Tools', I can see the request repeating every 200 milliseconds which I feel is a little odd.

I don't know if it's bad for the site or browser. If it won't hamper on site and user browser then it's fine, but if it does then how? And if it is the case, can I remove the old requests automatically after the new one been created?

Comment: you wanna request your server 5 times / sec?? you are actually spamming your site.

Comment: From what you describe about the network tab this is standard behaviour - you're seeing a list of every request being made. I would say though that this seems very excessive. Sending a request every 200ms will place a lot of demand on your server, to the point where your hosting company may throttle you. Have you instead looked in to using websockets?

Comment: Making a request so frequently will definitely hamper the performance, i would not advise you to do so, but if you really want to do declare a global bool variable set the value to true on the success of the request,  success: function (data) {
                        if (data == 1) {
                            setTimeout("update", 10000);
                        }
                    },

Comment: @CerlinBoss i am creating a notification feature on my project work with some simple concept of Server-Sent Events.

Comment: I don't have that much knowledge on webscokets @RoryMcCrossan.I was trying some small code with some Server-Sent Events concept.Is there any way to make new request after checking and killing/removing if there are some old request?

Comment: Think about how many people will be accessing the site at the same time. 100 visitors watching the same page = 500 requests per second. Your server will probably not like it...

Comment: @atornblad ok now I understood about the problem.Can any one help me by providing a good solution on current code of mine?

Comment: The network tab is doing exactly what it should do - showing you all network activity. What you could try is simply stopping the recording. If you are using Chrome, it's the red circle.

Comment: I want my code to make new request after the old one is killed or remove what possible.Is there any way to handle this all by `jquery/javascript` or `php`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand why every 200ms?! Bit excessive perhaps? However, something like an FX tracker would make a plausible use-case.

I suggest you use different technology though: **WebSockets**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications

http://socket.io/

P.s. the network tab is showing exactly what you are doing - i.e. a request every 200ms. You can't minify this into 1 entry.

Comment: I am creating a notification feature on my project work.My code hides for longer if i increase the time.I mean I was on such situation where I need to select `id's/classe's` for some function from those data inside update function and if my time is greater it displays my data lately which doesn't let me perform any function with those `id's/classe's`.

Comment: Don't quite understand what you mean :) But I would definitely switch to sockets for notifications. Check out socket.io it's exactly for your use-case.

Comment: I know @Stevanicus there are alot of way but isn't it possible with my way?I mean I only want to reduces the pressure of client and server.I want to kill or remove the old request before a new request is made.Can we do that or not?

Comment: Sockets reduce that "pressure". It's built with that in mind - that's the whole point. Don't use AJAX for that. If you program a WebSocket yourself or use Socket.io - they are still JavaScript solutions.

Comment: Then you don't need to worry about cancelling request etc. You simply push the new data from the server.

Comment: I have seen some video using Node.js & Socket.io but I have seen them using on localhost.How can we use it from server/hosting?

Comment: You need a server/host which allows Node JS :)